# React with Google Apps Script

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, web-applications

Has anyone tried deploying a React front end to a Google Apps Script web app?  I'm trying to build a single page front end that calls some of the Google Apps Script apis, like get a list of drive files and save some results to a spreadsheet.  However, all the React docs seem to assume I'm using a Node.js backend and don't focus much on custom build/deploy situations.  If you have seen even a simple hello world for React with Google Apps Script, would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Check out gas-react on npm. It is really easy to use. Handles all of your server bundling etc

Answer (score 13):

I have zero experience with React, but their starter 'Hello, World' example from the docs is working as expected inside HTML templates. The script below is spreadsheet-bound, but the same is applicable to web apps.

Note that the attribute `type="text/babel"` for the `<script>` tag is required.

sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body id="root">

  <script type="text/babel">

   ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result in Google Sheets sidebar:

[image]

Comment: This became possible thanks to [iFrame Sandbox Mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) In the past it was not very simple. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Hey @oshliaer can you expand why iFrame Sandbox mode makes this simpler, please?

Comment: @ASKER All sandbox modes are now sunset except for IFRAME. It's not important now.

Answer (score 9):

Lot of great projects here. Also including a full-featured demo app, showing how to use React with google apps script:

https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script

It uses clasp and webpack, so you can use all the new javascript you want for your .gs server-side code (such as arrow functions, `const`/`let`, etc.)

Comment: The one issue I take with this, is that there is no support for any state management system, such as MobX...

If there existed a version of MobX that could be used with this project, I would have hopped on this train!

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/marth141/react-gas

Know this question was asked a long time ago but I just wrote up a thing on Google Apps Script that is React.

You can use this as like a boilerplate. Use clasp in the src folder to push and pull code to Google Apps Script

Comment: I saw your post when I scrolled down... Your boilerplate is awesome! I hope my answer doesn't take away from your hard work. If you think it does I can take it down, no problem.

Comment: Not at all! It's totally cool man :) The more code, the merrier!

Comment: Is it possible to use Redux DevTools from within Google Sheets?

Comment: @pauljeba I'm going to be honest, I do not know. I've seen some other crazier users of JavaScript in Google Apps Script.

This solution is pretty old, using before the V8 Engine and TypeScript of today. However, it still seems like a regular way to make things work is to use CDNs... I think you probably could and there might be a better method out there :)!

Answer (score 3):

I was totally inspired by Anton's amazing idea!! So great!! To add to his idea here is an appscript with module like behaviour and a base App class and I have added redux into the mix.

Code.gs

```
function include(filename) {
Logger.log(filename)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
        var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle(
            'Flashcards');
        SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

App.js.html

```
<script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>Hello World</div>
    )
  }
}

</script>
```

index.js.html - without redux

```
  <script type="text/babel">
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
```

index.js.html - with redux

```
<script type="text/babel">  
   const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider
   ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
     </Provider>, 
     document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    // Libraries for adding redux
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.7/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <?!= include('App.js'); ?>
  // pull in redux if and when needed
  <?!= include('redux.js'); ?>
  <?!= include('index.js'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

redux.js.html

```
<script type="text/babel">      
  const initialState = {
    result: 1, 
    lastValues: []
  }


  const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
      case "ADD": 
          state = {
            ...state,
            result : state.result + action.payload,
            lastValues: [...state.lastValues, action.payload]
          }          
        break;
    }
    return state;
  };  
  const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

  store.subscribe( () => {
    console.log('Store updated!', store.getState());
  })

  store.dispatch({ type: "ADD", payload: 10 })
</script>
```

Comment: Btw, isn't it prohibited to use single page application frameworks in GAS add-ons?

Comment: Were you able to see state changes in Redux DevTools from within Google Sheets?